# Unable to add object fetched from mongoDB to normal javascript array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, ejs

I am trying to create an add to cart button which fetches the data from product database using the id of specific product which I selected. I am trying to push the object found using the same Id into a normal javascript array and then to display it using ejs methods. While I was tring I found I am unable to push the data in object form.

Summary:

On 7th line I have declared an array and in that array I want to store some objects which I have fetched frome a db model.
On 15th line I am trying to push the object form into my array so that I could iterate through the objects to display them on my page using ejs. But I am unable to do that.

screenshots:

1. Here's the final result I'm getting even after trying to push objects in array:

[empty array logged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQ8zO.png)

2. Here are the objects I'm trying to push:

[Objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSL9l.png)

Code:

```js
app.get("/cart", (req, res) => {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        const findcartdata = req.user.username;
        userData.findOne({email: findcartdata}, (err, BookId) => {
            // console.log(BookId.cartItemId);
            const idArray = BookId.cartItemId;
            var bookArray = [];
            idArray.forEach((data) => {
                productData.findOne({_id: data}, (err, foundBookData) =>{
                    // console.log(foundBookData);
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    else{
                        bookArray.push(foundBookData);
                    }
                })
            });
            console.log(bookArray);
            // res.render("cart", {
            //     cartBookArray: BookId.cartItemId
            // })
        });
    } else {
        res.redirect("/login");
    }
})
```

In above code i found the user's email using passport authentication user method and using that email I wanted to add the products in a different javascript array (which I am goint to  pass to my ejs file of cart and then iterate it on list) using those array of Id which I got from another model called userData. The problem is I am able to find userData of each Id but  unable to store them as an array of objects.

Comment: you are not waiting for the Your second promise/callback. ` console.log(bookArray);` this should be run only after you got the results of second array., do it using async await or promiseAll

Comment: Hey Sojin, I tried using async-await but it's not working. Here's the error I got:


nhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Query was already executed: productData.findOne({ _id: new ObjectId("6177e7b5aaa6cae0d4c...
    at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOne] (D:\Mohit\Web\INT 220 - final project\BookStore\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\wrapThunk.js:21:19)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a timing issue, your code completes before the database downloads the objects and pushes them to your array.

This should fix your issue:

```js
// ...
const idArray = BookId.cartItemId;
var bookArray = [];
for (const data of idArray) {
    const foundBookData = await productData.findOne({_id: data}).catch(console.error);
    if (!foundBookData) continue;
    bookArray.push(foundBookData);
}

console.log(bookArray);
// ...
```

By the way, make sure to make the whole function asynchronous as well, which would be done by changing this line:

```js
userData.findOne({email: findcartdata}, async (err, BookId) => { // ...
```

Comment: Hey, The method you mentioned is throwing an error:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Query was already executed: productData.findOne({ _id: new ObjectId("6177e7b5aaa6cae0d4c...
    at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOne] (D:\Mohit\Web\INT 220 - final project\BookStore\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\wrapThunk.js:21:19)

Comment: I edited my answer, can you take a look at the new version ?

Comment: Thanks man, I guess I need to learn the concepts of javascript promises again. Well done.